# Downloading zip and parsing csv file in django, copying data to local DB(sqllite)

Tags: python, django, zip

I have a url, which downloads a zip file, containing a csv file. I want to parse the data and import it to local Database(sqlite) in Django.

In brief, input = url, pre-processing download .zip-> convert to .csv, output=csv rows in DB which has columns of csv as fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think if you google a bit you can do it yourself. I will give you the keyword:

- For download a file you can you use request:

> import requests
>
> url = 'https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico'
> r = requests.get(url,
> allow_redirects=True)
>
> open('facebook.ico', 'wb').write(r.content)

- To parse a csv file use xlsxwriter
- To save the data to database, I suggest you save the data to  django model then call model.save()

To use django on standalone script read this

[How to import Django Settings to python standalone script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821825/how-to-import-django-settings-to-python-standalone-script)

To use it as a service you should use rest_framework and write a custom viewset like this. I had quite a hard time get familiar with it, so good luck, but when you get long, drf is quite handy tool for everything, just not fast.

https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/django-rest-framework-viewset-when-you-don-t-have-a-model-335a0490ba6f

You should django settings to save the path to temp file. In linux you can use /tmp

Comment: So I have to create a .py file say temp.py, there I have to use request, xlsxwriter, import django model to add the rows and save it. 1) My doubt is how do I make sure this python script runs, when I start the server(use python manage.py runserver). 2)Also where should I put that file(inside project root/app root), sorry for asking silly questions, new to development. At the end of the day, when someone visits my site the url data keeps changing every hour, so the python script should run whenever someone visits my site and load the respective data.

Comment: You need to run this once or as a service? If once just python3 script_name.py

Comment: Whenever I open the website(GET request) the script should run and display data accordingly.